# How to get vowels, consonants and other characters from a text

Tags: python, parsing, for-loop, while-loop

I need a program that asks the user to enter any text and then display three strings, the first of which consists of all the vowels from the text, the second, of all consonants, and the third, of all other characters. I have it in a while loop right now, I was wondering how I can transfer that into a for-loop in Python.

```
text = input("Enter text: ")

# Loop counter
i = 0

# Accumulators
vows_string = ""
cons_string = ""
other_str = ""

while i < len(text):
    char = text[i]
    if char in "aioueAIOUE":
        vows_string += char
    elif char.isalpha():
        cons_string += char
    else:
        other_str += char
    i += 1

# Add pseudo-guillemets to make spaces "visible"
print(">>" + vows_string + "<<")
print(">>" + cons_string + "<<")
print(">>" + other_str + "<<")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since strings are iterable, you can replace

```
while i < len(text):
    char = text[i]
```

with

```
for char in text:
    # no more need for 'i'
```

By the way, try `if char.lower() in "aioue":`

Comment: Argh, 17 seconds too late, had to reread the question to figure out what was needed.

Comment: Thank you, it worked and made my code a lot more simple

Answer (score 0):

Now that the code is simple, let's make it potentially more efficient by using a `set()` for the vowels instead of a string:

```
# Vowels Set
vowels = set("aeiouAEIOU")

# Accumulators
vowels_string = ""
consonants_string = ""
other_string = ""

# User Input
text = input("Enter text: ")

# Process Text
for char in text:
    if char.isalpha():
        if char in vowels:
            vowels_string += char
        else:
            consonants_string += char
    else:
        other_string += char

# Add pseudo-guillemets to make spaces "visible"
print("<<", vowels_string, ">>", sep="")
print("<<", consonants_string, ">>", sep="")
print("<<", other_string, ">>", sep="")
```